# problem package ethzasl_icp_mapping

Tags: ros, ethzasl-icp-mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I have a problem with ubuntu 12.04, `ros-hydro and ethzasl_icp_mapping`
I searched the package but I couldn't found it

```
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-ethzasl-icp-mapping
```

**Is the package avaiable for ros-hydro?**, because I found only for ros groovy and fuerte.

I tried to compile from source but I have a problem at compile time with `libpointmatcher_ros` is it a boost problem?  from the last lines of the log it's seems to be libboost problem with shared_ptr.

**Did someone had the same problem?**

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191361/problem-package-ethzasl_icp_mapping/) by [amd_best](https://answers.ros.org/users/20094/amd_best/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-08-27

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-08-27**:
It should be available for hydro but the jenkins jobs are failing. See on the [wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/ethzasl_icp_mapping). Maybe you contact the maintainers.

**Comment by [ajain](https://answers.ros.org/users/18985/ajain/) on 2014-10-01**:
I moved to ROS Indigo, and I want to use ethzaasl_icp_mpping package. Apparently, the last release has been only for hydro. Though, I found "indigo_devel" branch on git, Not sure if it needs to run differently or there are some code changes yet to be pushed, but it builds fine but crashes on runtime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Fortunately, I got in touch with François Pomerleau (maintainer of ethzasl_icp_mapping repo). Got very useful information from him. All packages were recently catkinized for easy migration reasons. There are two branches with this code - "catkinized" and "indigo-devel". Both of them are missing libnabo and libpointmatcher packages. For the missing libpointmacher / libnabo packages, they were catkinized too and are now fetch directly as dependency from:
https://github.com/ethz-asl/libpointmatcher-release
https://github.com/ethz-asl/libnabo-release

He also mentioned that icp_mapping package is very stable until fuerte, and he has received many e-mails regarding hydro package giving issues with boost library. So the problem that you are facing yet need to be solved.

One more very important thing I discovered while making icp_mapping work in indigo was that libpointmatcher library is not compatible with 32 bit computers, and only works well with 64 bit systems.  François said that libpointmatcher and libnabo are very stable and encouraged to use those libraries if we are interested in creating our own mapping package.

---

Originally posted by [ajain](https://answers.ros.org/users/18985/ajain/) with karma: 281 on 2014-10-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kailegh](https://answers.ros.org/users/21460/kailegh/) on 2016-06-16**:
could you please explain me how to install it in indigo? I try everything but I still do not get it to work